# Создание своего бота для CS2

Tags: python, разработка-игр, компьютерное-зрение

Подскажите как создать бота для игры CS2. Необходимо чтобы он ходил за ближайшим союзником и при виде врага наводился на него и стрелял.

Я не знаю какие библиотеки использовать и где можно посмотреть практику создания чего то похожего. Хотел написать это на языке программирования Python

Comment: Смотрите в сторону компьютерного зрения. К примеру, можете покрутить библиотеку опенсв.